# node-webkit http.Server and page change

Tags: node.js, subprocess, node-webkit

I write an application using node-webkit. I want to use HTTP for network communication between  computers, running my app. Can I change current page without server restart if server was started from the page?

I thought about child process, but I want to shutdown the server with my application. I don't want to use special network request to the server to close it.

Can I change current page without server restart?
Can I save child process object while page changing?
Do you know other way to do this?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the node-webkit documentation.

> In node-webkit, you can basically do the same thing by using
>   `window.location`, you can install it in the `onclick` event of a link and
>   node-webkit will navigate to a new page when user clicks it. But by
>   doing this you would lose everything in `window` context, you can save
>   everything in cookies like old web pages, or you can save things in
>   the `global` variable, which resides in Node.js's context and will live
>   through your app.